# Omit extraction based on texts

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, imacros

I'm sorry if I'm not very clear, English is not my native language.

What I need is to create a code to feed a horse, the first thing to do is extract the number 10 as seen in the picture [Click for view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGFtJ.png) and mark it in the panel below, but if the warning appears,you need to select 20, but when appears the warning 2 , do not give anything to the horse. It may sound stupid my problem but it can get you to serve more than one.

For now I have all this elaborate

This code what it does is extract the number 10

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG XPATH="//form[@id='feeding']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span[2]/strong" 
EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR1}}
```

Now what I need is to extract the number 20 from the warning "If available"

```
<span class="grid-cell">Caution: your horse is underweight, give him 20 
fodder today to bring him back into shape!</span>
```

Or select nothing if appear the by down

```
<span class="grid-cell">Your horse is getting too fat. Don't give him 
anything to eat today so he can get back to his regular weight!</span>
```

For that I had to use EVAL: http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Caution:
<SP>your<SP>horse<SP>is<SP>underweigh,* EXTRACT=TXT
        'To remove punctuation marks and words I had to add them here
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\$|abCcdefghiklmnoprstuvwy 
|:!,]/g, '');")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The description is not clear enough but I try to help you with the following code:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG XPATH="//form[@id='feeding']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span[2]" EXTRACT=TXT

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET posSpan EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\d+/)) ? 1 : 0;")
SET txtSpan EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\d+/);")
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS={{posSpan}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:{{txtSpan}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear, now try to detail everything :S

Comment: Unfortunately not, anyway thank you for trying to help :D

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved here [Click for view](http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=27919&sid=b4c7651573007e3224d65de01322c8e4)  thanks for everything :]

Here is my finished code:

```
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=ON
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG XPATH="//form[@id='feeding']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span[2]/strong" 
EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
'>
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 1
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Caution:
<SP>your<SP>horse<SP>is<SP>underweigh,* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/[\\$|abCcdefghiklmnoprstuvwy 
|:!,]/g, '');")

SET !VAR3 EVAL("var n1='{{!VAR1}}', n2='{{!VAR2}}'; if((n1*1)>(n2*1)){var x 
= \" {{!VAR1}}\";} else {var x=\"{{!VAR2}}\";} x;")

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:{{!VAR3}}
```